# Windows network copy produces high latency

Tags: windows-7, networking

We started using Windows 10 Pro at home and I have a problem when other computers start using my shared files (copy movies fore example). If another PC starts coping, my network usage goes up to 100% percent and I can't do anything that uses internet connection, becouse I have ~500ms pings.

While I copy a file from another computer and  If I pause it:
[image] [image].

I tried disabling "Large Send Offload V2 IPv4", but did not helped. Why it is putting such a high load on my network card, when the speed of the coping is only 11MB/s??

Comment: Your NIC is running at 100 MBit/s. That’s just too slow. You should look into that.

Comment: What should it be set to? I only have the option of 10/100/1G, but if I set it to 1G It wont connect to the network saying I have no link.

Comment: Then either the other end of the connection (a switch or whatever) is not Gigabit-capable or the cable is too low-quality.

Comment: That is not the problem, I don't care if it is slow, It can wait, The problem is that even if it is only copying with 11mb/s it uses the network card at 100% and I cant use my computer while it is doing that.

Comment: Well of course. That’s why I’m telling you: 100 MBit/s = 12,5 MiB/s. Your network connection is saturated. You need a faster network connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be confused about the “network load” percentage displayed in Task Manager. This number doesn’t refer to some abstract metric. Instead, it refers to used vs. (theoretically) available bandwidth (bw).

That means 99% used * 100 MBit/s available bw = 99 MBit/s used bw.

99 MBit/s = 12.375 MiB/s. You say you’re currently copying with a net speed of 11 MiB/s. Add some overhead (which is inevitable when using Windows File Sharing and the like) and you’re at said 12.375 MiB/s.

**Bottom line**: Your network link is completely busy. That means even the smallest stuff like ping or browsing is delayed.

**How to resolve the situation?** Upgrade the connection. 100 MBit/s is simply not suitable for today’s data volumes. That’s why all modern PCs ship with a 1 GBit/s network interface. It’s been that way for many years now. All you need to utilize that speed is a reasonable cable (CAT 5e+) and a Gigabit-capable switch (like $20).

At 1 GBit/s = 125 MiB/s you’re even faster than some mechanical HDDs.